# Dynamic programming with Fibonacci

Tags: java, optimization, fibonacci-sequence, dynamic-programming, memoization

I have written the following code using a dynamic programming technique.  Can I use `ArrayList` here?  Please let me know if I can improve this code.

```
package com.java.fib;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Fibonaci {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(" number ");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HashMap<Integer, BigInteger> memoized = new HashMap<Integer, BigInteger>();
         fibonanci(220, memoized);
        System.out.println(" Total Time "
                + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    }

    private static BigInteger fibonanci(int n, HashMap<Integer, BigInteger> memoized) {
        if (memoized.containsKey(n)) {
            return memoized.get(n);
        }
        if (n <= 0) {
             return BigInteger.ZERO;
        }
        if (n <= 2) {
            return BigInteger.ONE;
        } else {
            BigInteger  febonani = fibonanci(n - 1, memoized).add (fibonanci(n - 2, memoized));
            System.out.println(" febonani " + febonani);
                memoized.put(n, febonani);
            return febonani;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

A few things:

## Naming:

It's neither `Fibonaci`, nor `febonani`, nor `fibonanci` it's `fibonacci`. Please get your names to reflect what you're actually talking about and not some disfigured mutation of it :(

`memoized` OTOH is a relatively nice name, I'd probably prefer `memoizedFibonacciNumbers`, but that's a thing of preference

## Calculating:

[quoting wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)

> By definition, the first two numbers in the Fibonacci sequence are \$1\$ and \$1\$, or \$0\$ and \$1\$, depending on the chosen starting point of the sequence, and each subsequent number is the sum of the previous two.

You on the other hand say:

> The value of Fibonacci for \$n <= 0\$ is \$0\$, and for \$n <= 2\$ is \$1\$, and each subsequent number is the sum of the previous two.

Wikipedia also mentions ["negative Fibonacci numbers"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#List_of_Fibonacci_numbers). Your definition does not match the actual Fibonacci sequence definition :(

instead your fibonacci method should look like this, if you exactly follow the rules for only positive fibonacci numbers:

```
private static BigInteger fibonacci(Integer n, HashMap<Integer, BigInteger> memoized) {
    if (n < 0) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("We assume the positive Fibonacci sequence only");
    }
    if (memoized.containsKey(n)) {
        return memoized.get(n);
    }
    if (n == 0) {
        memoized.put(n, BigInteger.ZERO);
        return memoized.get(n);
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        memoized.put(n, BigInteger.ONE);
        return memoized.get(n);
    }
    BigInteger fibonacci = fibonacci(n-1, memoized).add(fibonacci(n-2, memoized));
    memoized.put(n, finbonacci);
    return fibonacci;
}
```

## Printing is ***slow***:

I see you benchmarking your code. Please keep in mind, that writing something to the Console is quite slow. Your measured execution time is not matching the calculation time.

You should remove the `System.out.println()` in your fibonacci method.

## Conditionals

Also you maybe have already realized, I removed the `else` in the fibonacci method.

This is because if your code reaches that area, all other branches have returned early, and the else is quite useless.

Comment: Maybe "memorized" instead of "memoized"?

Comment: Let my native Russian fix your native German :)

Comment: No, he means memoized, *without the r*. Memoization is a technique where you cache results of computations that are likely to be repeated. In particular, it's used often in recursive functions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

Comment: @Schism caught between two worlds... ahem. After seing the wikipedia article I think I will just roll back my own edits...

Answer (score 8):

[@Vogel612](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/57647/32231) has already mentioned all major defects and areas of improvement in your code. I want to talk about one more thing:

Your package naming is horrible. You are using `com.java.fib`, please do not ever do that again, because:

1. Although Java classes are prefixed with `java.*`, it still creates confusion as people might think this is a library class. In extreme cases when you use professional names, it might even lead to a name clash.
2. You are pretending to *be* or have anything to do with `java.com`, which you really aren't and haven't.
3. Change it to something imaginary or existing. Use your own name, or your own website, I usually use `com.skiwi.*`.
4. Even `com.skiwi.fib` would be horrible because it offers barely any extra information, `com.java.fib.Fibonacci` is not helpful, consider something along the lines of `com.skiwi.algorithms`, in which the class `Fibonacci` can be found.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use ArrayList. A lookup in the list with get(220) will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Your list is not initialized by default.
What you can do is to use an array for your values. It allows you to check, if an index is already filled (via != null). On the other hand, you'll have to predefine the size of your array.
Also you'll have to check for indexbounds as well.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final BigInteger[] fibonacciCache = new BigInteger[221];
    fibonacciCache[0] = BigInteger.ZERO;
    fibonacciCache[1] = BigInteger.ONE;
    fibonacci(220, fibonacciCache);
}

private static BigInteger fibonacci(int n, final BigInteger[] fibonacciCache) {
    if (n<0) n=0;
    if (fibonacciCache[n]!=null) {
      return fibonacciCache[n];
    }
    fibonacciCache[n] = fibonacci(n - 1, fibonacciCache).add(fibonacci(n - 2, fibonacciCache));
    return fibonacciCache[n];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the things other people have mentioned (notably throwing an error on negative numbers and correcting the spelling), I would reorder some of the functionality and add more `else`s like so:

```
    private static BigInteger fibonacci(int n, HashMap<Integer, BigInteger> memoized)
    {
            if (n <= 0) {
                 return BigInteger.ZERO;
            } else if (n <= 2) {
                return BigInteger.ONE;
            } else if (memoized.containsKey(n)) {
                return memoized.get(n);
            } else {
                BigInteger  result = fibonacci(n - 1, memoized).add (fibonacci(n - 2, memoized));
                memoized.put(n, result);
                return result;
            }
    }
```

I'd also suggest that instead of making the user provide the memoized hash, you instead make a private static hash. Aside from making less work for the user, this would also allow you to preload the hash with the values of 0, 1 and 2, meaning you could strim out some of the function's logic and make it simpler.

```
    private static HashMap<Integer, BigInteger> memoizedHash;
    static
    {
        memoizedHash = new HashMap<Integer, BigInteger>();
        memoizedHash.put(0, BigInteger.ZERO);
        memoizedHash.put(1, BigInteger.ONE);
        memoizedHash.put(2, BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    private static BigInteger fibonacci(int n)
    {
        assert (n >= 0) : "This function does not accept negative numbers";
        if (memoizedHash.containsKey(n)) {
            return memoizedHash.get(n);
        } else {
            BigInteger  result = fibonacci(n - 1).add (fibonacci(n - 2));
            memoizedHash.put(n, result);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code will result in a stackoverflow when called with negative numbers!

Comment: "Aside from the things other people have mentioned (notably throwing an error on negative numbers and correcting the spelling)" Opening sentence implying I am not mentioning those things because other posts have covered them.

Comment: I'd prefer having it explicitly added.

Comment: @Vogel612 Any reason other than preference?

Comment: People can be unexpectedly dumb :( but how you handle that is yours to decide ;)

Comment: @Vogel612 I'd like to handle that by letting the program crash. This will A) encourage them to find out why, B) punish them for not knowing why and C) stop them from lazily copy-pasting code they found on stack overflow without thinking about it. But as that's probably really mean, I'll do something nobody else here has done yet to add educational value to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ArrayList` instead of `HashMap` here.

**Update:**

After some comments, I reimplement using non-recursive way, it took a bit longer than your source code (15 ms in comparison with 11 ms running on my computer), but most of time is spent to print output by `System.out.println` function. There is a small difference, I added 3 first numbers of Fibonaci sequence (0, 1, 1) to the result array.

```
public class Fibonaci {

    public static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<BigInteger> memoized = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fibonanci(220, memoized);

        for(int i = 0; i < memoized.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(" febonani " + memoized.get(i));
        }

        System.out.println(" Total Time " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    }

    private static BigInteger fibonanci(int n, ArrayList<BigInteger> memoized) {
        BigInteger febonani = BigInteger.ZERO;
        int size = memoized.size();
        if (n < 0) {
            return BigInteger.ZERO;
        }
        if (size > n) {
                febonani = memoized.get(n);
        } else {
            for(int i = size; i <= n; i++) {
                if(i == 0) {
                    febonani = BigInteger.ZERO;
                } else if(i == 1 || i == 2) {
                    febonani = BigInteger.ONE;
                } else {
                    febonani = memoized.get(i - 1).add(memoized.get(i - 2));
                }
                memoized.add(febonani);
            }
        }
        return febonani;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to elaborate a bit on why `ArrayList` is better than `HashMap`. Additionally you should declare `memoized` as a `List<BigInteger>`. That makes swapping `ArrayList` for e.g. `LinkedList` much easier

Comment: I tried to replace but encountered this error: *The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments*

Comment: You use the wrong import. Don't use `java.awt.List`, but `java.util.List`

Comment: IS the logic of using ArrayList is correct  for 2 the fibonacci value is 1 does your logic handle this

Comment: @VIckyb: yes, `if(n <= 2)` statement handled that. @Vogel612: import one of them return the same error.

Comment: @Dai : i mean to say n can be 100 but your adding to arraylist the value of 100 at may 40 place suppose in that this may fail

Comment: When using an `ArrayList`, you really need to be sure that the values are put on the correct indexes. I feel that you cannot be that certain about that here. Your code here returns the sequence `0 1 1 2 3 4 7 11 18 36` which is incorrect. I would definitely go with a `Map<Integer, BigInteger>` instead.

Comment: @DaiNguyen-Van sorry if that sounds blunt. Can you *read*? I told you to **not** import `java.awt.List`, but *instead* `java.util.List`. Importing the util List should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks you so much for all your comments. I saw the problem in my old implementation. I already updated with non-recursive way to keep using `ArrayList`. Dear @Vogel612, I tried using `List` as your recommendation, it didn't raise that error but took longer than `ArrayList`, it can be my way is not good. I will be happy if you can edit my code to make it better.

Comment: what I mean is: `List<BigInteger> memoized = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();`... this should keep your running time in the same level. I did **not** recommend using LinkedList. It is just the reason you should be programming against interfaces, and not implementations.

Comment: On my side, after using declaration as you said: `List<BigInteger> memoized = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();`, time was increased to 22ms. That is reason I keep `ArrayList` on both sides of that declaration.

Comment: @DaiNguyen-Van What's a 'febonani'?

Comment: @Pharap Fibonaci sequence definition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). I think it's not too difficult to understand it. In fact, most of Fibonaci implementation using recursion so my way might be not familiar but it shows the same result with traditional way.

Comment: @DaiNguyen-Van I was hinting that the spelling was incorrect: 'febonani' as opposed to 'Fibonacci'. And recursion is a common way to implement it as it allows compilers to use tail call optimisation.

Comment: I followed the questioner, reuse his source code.